# Why can I not reuse a method in an Ajax form in a partial view?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC Application that has a basic ajax form for submitting data. After the form, there is a partial view which has another ajax form in it for submitting data to a drop-down box allowing users to update its contents without leaving the page.

**Create**

```
@model My Project.Models.Cars

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Cars", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    ... form fields would be here ...
}
@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")
```

**Partial View(_Manufacturer)**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddManufacturer", "AnotherController", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

    ... form fields for populating dropdown list ...
}
```

When I try to submit the ajax form in the partial view I am getting an error of:

> 404 Resource Not Found at Cars/AddManufacturer

The controller it's supposed to use is `AnotherController` as you can see in the form above.  I don't want to have to create multiple forms and methods, I want to reuse the method I have.  Is there a reason it's doing this and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes partials render URLs differently accordingly to where they are called from.

Inspect your page and see if the URL rendered on the second form is right. If that is the case then find a method overload that can resolve the route correctly.

Here is a list of the overloads:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd492974(v=vs.118)

Comment: When I look at the source code for the entire page, the controller part of the form is rendered as "action="/Test/AddManufacturer?Length=7" adding `null` to `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddManufacturer", "AnotherController", null, new AjaxOptions` seems to solve the problem :)

Comment: so you called a different method overload that specifies how to resolve the route better

Comment: Indeed I have.  It seems to work without any problems.